Elliptic operators over noncompact manifold
We know for two vector bundles $E$ and $F$ over compact manifold $M$,an elliptic operator $D:\Gamma(\mathrm{E})\to \Gamma(\mathrm{F})$ is automatically Fredholm.
And for the case $M$ is noncompact, in particular manifolds with cylindrical ends,in this paper: http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_1985_4_12_3_409_0.pdf
Lockhart and McOwens introduce the notion weighted Soblev spaces and show that, after putting a suitable weighted Soblev space structure on $\Gamma(\mathrm{E})$ and $\Gamma(\mathrm{F})$, the translation invariant elliptic operators $D_{inv}:\Gamma(\mathrm{E})\to \Gamma(\mathrm{F})$ are still fredholm, it’s also true even we slightly perturbe $D_{inv}$.
However this beautiful result by Lockhart and Owen requires some assumptions on operator itself.I wonder for any elliptic operator $D:\Gamma(\mathrm{E})\to \Gamma(\mathrm{F})$, is it possible to put a suitable boundary condition on $\Gamma(\mathrm{E})$ and $\Gamma(\mathrm{F})$ such that $D:\Gamma(\mathrm{E})\to \Gamma(\mathrm{F})$ is fredholm?

Solutions of the Laplace equation $\Delta u = 0$ include harmonic polynomials, which grow at most polynomially, each $|u(x)| \le C |x|^N$ for some $N>0$ depending on $u$. Define $D[v] = e^{-g(x)} \Delta (e^{g(x)} v)$ as an elliptic operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Its solutions include just $v(x) = e^{-g(x)} u(x)$ for any harmonic polynomial $u(x)$. Since $g(x)$ can grow arbitrarily fast as $|x|\to \infty$, it can be chosen so that infinitely many solutions of $D[v] = 0$ are bounded, or even decay faster than $e^{-g(x)+\varepsilon|x|}$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. So $D[v]$ is not Fredholm on any weighted function space that doesn't exclude these solutions.
The point of this observation is that it is probably hopeless that expect some standard set of weights in Lebesgue or Sobolev spaces are enough to make an arbitrary elliptic operator Fredholm on a non-compact domain. Likely, one can't avoid making some assumption about the asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of $D[v]$ at its non-compact ends.

Although I am a big fan of Lockhart and McOwens papers, many of the their results can easily be proved from the results of the paper of Atiyah, Patodi, Singer,Spectral Asymmetry and Riemannian Geometry.  In particular Proposition 2.5 is a hairs breath away from the key result in the first order case.

Let me add one more comment.  The slogan for what is going on is that to get a Fredholm operator on a non-compact manifold you need "invertibility outside compact sets" for the operator on suitable spaces.  Sometimes geometry can help for example the is Gromov and Lawson's paper [POSITIVE SCALAR CURVATURE
AND THE DIRAC OPERATOR
ON COMPLETE RIEMANNIAN MANIFOLDS]{https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/840.pdf} where positive scalar curvature outside a compact set on a complete Riemannian manifold is enough to get a Fredholm Dirac operator.
